# How to use DB indexes with Datatables and yajra/laravel-datatables

Tags: mysql, datatables, laravel-5.1

So far when I try column filtering I'm able to use LIKE or REGEXP but nether of them are using table indexes, which is a great concern given the amount of data I need to filter.

Is there a way to get an exact match using indexes? (DB indexes)

I'm using:
https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables v6.11.3 and
https://datatables.net v1.10.10

Comment: Did you try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9580647/how-to-use-a-full-text-index-for-exact-matches

Comment: Thank you, but that is different, my question is about datatables. What I want to achieve using yajra/laravel-datatables is search by column using exact match instead of like "%search%" or REGEXP. My goal is to use my table index to avoid full table scans.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With datatables laravel package you can customise parameter search on laravel side in lookup function with the "**filterColumn**" function. Like so:

```
    return Datatables::of($users)
        ->filterColumn('user_id', function($query, $keyword) {
            $query->whereRaw("CONCAT(users.id,'-',users.id) like ?", ["%{$keyword}%"]);
        })
        ->make(true);
```

See more in [Documentation](http://datatables.yajrabox.com/eloquent/post-column-search)